# SharePoint 2013 Document and/or List Library Grouping

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

How would I create the following in SharePoint 2013 (see image below):

Is there a way to group documents by two and have it seperated? See #1 in the image.  Also, is there a way to have different views assigned to different individuals?  For instance, if John Doe views the document library he would only see his assigned list.  Based on research, I believe the best way to handle part of the question by creating a document library. However, a List Library may work too, however, I am not sure if you can group documents by two.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont reiterate the answers above, however none of them seem to cover your biggest question: How to show only documents the user is Assigned To.

To do this, modify the view and in the Filters section, choose the "Assigned To" column. Then set the filter to "Equals" and the value to "[Me]".

This will only display the documents that have been set for the current user.

If you need more info or screenshots, let me know. I can't do much of that on my phone...

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your View's setting page, then in the Grouping area choose Doc#.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping would give headers that might not be desired, instead, you'd want to create a view that is sorted by Doc# ascending and Doc Name ascending.